# What is the most efficient option to stream a live video feed via http?

Tags: http, video-streaming, vlc

I'm trying to live stream my webcam and embed it on a webpage. In theory I achieved that by using VLC streaming.

[image]

[image]

I consume that stream locally from my webpage like this;

```
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1>
<video width="700" src="http://127.0.0.1:1234" autoplay type="video/ogg;">   </video>
</body></html>
```

This is working but there is a huge delay and lag when I share my screen and practically not working at all when I pick my webcam as a source.

Is there any more efficient way to achieve this via VLC player? If not what would be best option(framework, library, protocol, format etc.) to do the job?